# Tracing object access in Java

Tags: java, android, debugging

I have a large Android application. I have a set of classes that I want to trace how they are accessed during debugging. Objects of these classes should only be accessed from one thread. Different objects may be accessed by different threads, but one object should only be accessed by one thread.

I want to avoid cluttering up every method of the classes with verification code. Is there a simpler way to achieve this?

Comment: Sounds like an ideal use case for interceptors. I'm not sure how to use them in an android project though.